# Getting Strange Output from /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: software-center, dpkg

When I was installing updates, the Ubuntu Software Center progress bar got stuck, so I opened the terminal and tried to view contents which were working by running the command:

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

and the result was this which I didn't understand:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system
/run/user/1000/gvfs
       Output information may be incomplete.
```

Any help will be appreciated.